# long conversion C++ arduino

Tags: c++, arduino, infrared

I have this error, and I can't figure this out. 
cannot convert 'String' to 'long int' in assignment
I want to send all RC5 codes beetween 0x00 and 0xFF by IR led and arduino.
I am using IRremote
Here is my code :

```
for(int i = 0;i < 16 ;i++){
       value = i;
        if(i == 10){
          value = "a";
        }
                if(i == 11){
          value =  'b';
        }
                if(i == 12){
          value =  'c';
        }
                if(i == 13){
          value =  'd';
        }
                if(i == 14){
          value =  'e';
        }
                if(i == 15){
          value =  'f';
        }


         for(int j = 0;j < 16 ;j++){
       value2 = j;
        if(j == 10){
          value2 = "a";
        }
                if(j == 11){
          value2 =  'b';
        }
                if(j == 12){
          value2 =  'c';
        }
                if(j == 13){
          value2 =  'd';
        }
                if(j == 14){
          value2 =  'e';
        }
                if(j == 15){
          value2 =  'f';
        }
        valueTotal  = "0x" + value + value2;
        toSend = valueTotal;
        irsend.sendRC5(toSend , 12);
        delay(20);
    }  }
```

Comment: `value = "a";` Did you mean `value = 'a';`?  `""` denotes a string literal, but `''` denotes a char literal.

Comment: Also note that you can replace those `if .. else` blocks with `if (i >= 10) { value = (i - 10) + 'a'; }`

Comment: Also `valueTotal  = "0x" + value + value2;` will not do what you want.

Comment: Does your IR device really want a string?  Most of the time they want numbers.  You don’t have to convert decimal numbers to hex just because the code you saw had the numbers written in hex.  It doesn’t matter how you write a number the number itself and it’s binary representation doesn’t change.  You can probably just send i*16 + j.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using this library https://github.com/z3t0/Arduino-IRremote/blob/master/IRremote.h , `sendRC5` takes an unsigned long argument. You either seem to have got confused because of examples using hexadecimal literals into thinking it requires a string, or need to send your string as multiple words.

Assuming the former, something like this sends all the codes:

```
for (int i = 0x0; i <= 0xff ; ++i) {
    irsend.sendRC5(i, 12);
    delay(20);
}
```